# Returning sub-properties from document in RavenDb via Index using Lucene

Tags: indexing, lucene, ravendb

I'm using RavenDB 2.5 and what I want to do is query a `Group` (see below) providing a valid Lucene search term and get back a collection of `Member` instances (or even just Ids) that match. So, class definition:

```
public class Group {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Member {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
}
```

And they are stored in the database as `session.Store(groupInstance);` as you'd expect. What I'd like to do is query and return the `Member` instances which match a given search term.

So, something like:

```
public class GroupMembers_BySearchTerm : AbstractIndexCreationTask {
    public override IndexDefinition CreateIndexDefinition(){
        return new IndexDefinition {
            Map = "from g in docs.Groups select new { Content = new [] { g.Members.Select(m => m.Name), g.Members.Select(m => m.Bio) }, Id = g.Id }",
            Indexes = { { "Id", FieldIndexing.Default }, { "Content", FieldIndexing.Analyzed } }
        }
    }
}
```

If I call this using something like:

```
session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Group, GroupMembers_BySearchTerm>().Where("Id: myId AND Content: search terms").ToList();
```

I obviously get back a Group instance, but how can I get back the Members instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about an index like this:

```
public class Members_BySearchTermAndGroup : AbstractIndexCreationTask {
    public override IndexDefinition CreateIndexDefinition(){
        return new IndexDefinition {
            Map = "from g in docs.Groups
                   from member in g.Members
                   select new {
                   GroupdId = g.Id,
                   Name = member.Name,
                   Bio = member.Bio,
                   Content = new [] {member.Name, member.Bio },
                  }",
            Indexes = { 
                          { "GroupId", FieldIndexing.Default }, 
                          { "Content", FieldIndexing.Analyzed } 
                      },
            Stores = {
                          { "Name", FieldStorage.Yes },
                          { "Bio", FieldStorage.Yes }
                     }
        }
    }
}
```

If you take a closer look you'll see that we are creating a new lucene entry for each member inside of a group. Consequently, you'll be able to query on those elements and retrieve them.

---

Finally you can query your store like this (more info about [searching](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/indexes/querying/searching)):

```
session.Query<Member, Members_BySearchTermAndGroup>()
       .Search(x => x.Content, "search terms")
       .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<Member>()
       .ToList();
```

I cannot check this right now but I guess that you need to project your results using the ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto(). Some more information about projections in [this link](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/Csharp/client-api/querying/results-transformation/project-from-index-fields-into).

or, following your example:

```
session.Advanced
       .LuceneQuery<Member, Members_BySearchTermAndGroup>()
       .Where("GroupId: myId AND Content: search terms")
       .SelectFields<Member>()
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Firstly - this got me on the way, and is pretty much there, thank you! I had to do a couple of changes to get this to work: 1. using the `LuceneQuery` version - I had to put `.SelectFields<Member>` before the `ToList()` to do the projection. 2. I use the `Indexes` property for the index, but had to use the `Stores` property for the actual fields to be returned in the projection, i.e. `Stores = {{"Name", FieldStorage.Yes}, {"Bio", FieldStorage.Yes}}`

Comment: Glad to help. Yes, you need to use Stores because you want to store the fields in the lucene documents (I was in a bit of an hurry and missed that, sorry). Also I guess you don't need to index Name and Bio.

P.S.: I've updated my anwser with your feedback so thanks!